# What does it mean to have an $L$-basis of $L\otimes_K V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, tensor-products

**Exercise:** I have got a vector space $V$ over $K$, and $L$ a field extension of $K$. The task is to show that if $(v_1, ..., v_n)$ is a basis of $V$, then $(1\otimes_K v_1, ... ,1\otimes_K v_n)$ is an $L$-basis of $L\otimes_K V$.

**Question:** I know that I can consider $L$ as a vector space over $K$, so $L\otimes_K V$ is well-defined. But my question is more general, what does actually mean to have basis over $L$ for some vector space over $K$? Aren't we getting then a vector space over $L$?

And then what would it mean corresponding the exercise given? Because we have a tensor product over $K$, so basis over $L$ would be basis of tensor product over $L$, like $L\otimes_L V$, or am I wrong?

I hope the question is clear. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, $L\otimes_K V$ already has the structure of a vector space over $L$; the addition is the same as the one it has normally (i.e. as a $K$-vector space), and the scalar multiplication from $L$ is simply
$$\lambda\cdot (\alpha\otimes v)\overset{\text{def}}{=}(\lambda\alpha)\otimes v$$
where $\lambda,\alpha\in L$ and $v\in V$. Your task is then to show that the set described is a basis for this $L$-vector space.

This process can be done more generally, with $K$ being replaced by a ring $R$, and $L$ being replaced by any $R$-algebra. The process is known as [extension of scalars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_of_scalars). The analog of your question in this more general case is found in [this math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/370001/264).